# VSCode terminal previous commands

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I've been using the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code a lot since it was added, but I noticed a very frustrating feature/bug.

I am using the Windows 10 Bash terminal, and cannot seem to access the previous command history by using the "Up" arrows. Did this get remapped to another key or does it simply not work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70900927/836330 for how to bring up a QuickPick of recent terminal commands although I note that W10 bash is not currently supported.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer by accident, after accidentally hitting a few keys. It seems the most common commands have been mapped to the following defaults:

**Previous Command:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

**Next Command:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

**Cursor Left:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (backwards)

**Cursor Right:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (forwards)

**Cursor Home:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

**Cursor End:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (end)

**Delete from cursor position:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (del)

**Clear Screen:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: On Windows 10 and VScode 1.53.2, I had to change the following for the `Previous command` to work: `Keyboard shortcuts`-> Right click on `Go to File...` -> `Change when expression` -> `!terminalFocus`
Otherwise, Ctrl + P would always open the `Go to file` menu